# Reaching PHP Object sub elements

Tags: php, arrays, oop, object

Hello I've a respone object from outsource and I need to reach sub elements of the object.

Here is response I have :

```
object(Iyzipay\Model\Payment)#13 (32) {
  ["price":"Iyzipay\Model\PaymentResource":private]=>
  NULL
  ["paidPrice":"Iyzipay\Model\PaymentResource":private]=>
  NULL
  ["locale":"Iyzipay\IyzipayResource":private]=>
  string(2) "tr"
  ["systemTime":"Iyzipay\IyzipayResource":private]=>
  int(1568548407994)
  ["conversationId":"Iyzipay\IyzipayResource":private]=>
  string(13) "***_46_25"
  ["rawResult":"Iyzipay\ApiResource":private]=>
  string(156) "{"status":"failure","errorCode":"12","errorMessage":"Kart numarası geçersizdir","locale":"tr","systemTime":1568548407994,"conversationId":"***_46_25"}"
}
```

Here is php code :

```
$payment = \Iyzipay\Model\Payment::create($request, Config::options());
```

I have to reach elements like `$payment->rawResult` or `$payment->price` etc.

However I try lots of things to reach it but there is no way. Probably I don't know the reaching issue about object. Is there anyone know ?

I will interpret the response with make subobject as variable. Also I tried to make array from this object but there is no way too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those properties are private, so they can't be accessed directly from outside the class. Howwever, the class `Iyzipay\Model\Payment` extends other classes that extends even more classes. After following the code, I found that there are getters for most properties.

To get the two properties you mentioned, use:

```
$price     = $payment->getPrice();
$rawResult = $payment->getRawResult();
```

You can read more about property- and method visibility in the manual: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php